# Free English grammar checker

Tags: gratis, language

Which free grammar checker software would you recommend for people who learn English as a second language?

Comment: I use [Grammarly](http://grammarly.com) and it works well. It also checks for plagiarism.

Comment: @dimensio1n0 Grammarly is not free, in either of the two meanings of the word.

Comment: @user7610 Hm, then I guess I installed it when it used to be free (of cost).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org/) :

- Open Source proof-­reading soft­ware for English, French, German, Polish, and more than 20 other languages.
- Finds many errors that a simple spell checker cannot detect and several grammar problems.
- Available as standalone, Firefox add-on and LibreOffice/OpenOffice add-on.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Ginger](http://www.gingersoftware.com/):

- probably one of most popular free but not open source grammar checker software
- Windows/Mac/Android/iOS
- contains a grammar checker

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend Grammarly. It has both a free and paid edition with the free edition still giving great grammar recommendations for text. It is very easy to use and is available for Chrome, Firefox, and as a Windows application. You can also use the online interface too without having to install the application itself.

## [Grammarly](https://grammarly.com) (freemium)

> Grammarly Editor is an automated proofreader that corrects contextual spelling mistakes, checks for more than 250 common grammar errors, enhances vocabulary usage, and suggests citations.
>
> [image: Grammarly online editor UI]

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to recommend the Hemingway Editor. It is free to use online with a paid desktop app for offline use. The desktop app is available for Windows and OS X. The editor provides many different grammar and spelling corrections and you can format you text within the editor itself as well.

## [Hemmingway Editor](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/) (free online edition)

> Hemingway makes your writing bold and clear. It's like a spellchecker, but for style. It makes sure that your reader will focus on your message, not your prose.
> Too often, our words are like our thoughts — innumerable and disorganized. Almost any bit of writing could use some cutting. Less is more, etc.
> So, the Hemingway Editor will highlight (in yellow and red) where your writing is too dense. Try removing needless words or splitting the sentence into two. Your readers will thank you.
>
> [image: Hemingway Editor in action]